# Show that $(G, +, 0)$ and $(H, +, 0_{2×2})$ are abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G = \big\{a + b\sqrt2 | a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\big\}$.

Let $H = \bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} a & 2b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}\bigg |a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\bigg\} $

And denote $0_{2\times 2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,

then I have to show that $(G, +, 0)$ and $(H, +, 0_{2×2})$ are abelian groups. I know that a group is abelian if $\forall x,y \in G$ we have $x * y = y * x$.

Now, my problem is that I am not quite sure how to construct this proof. So any help/tip/example would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take two general elements $g,h \in G$ and compute $g + h$ and $h + g$. Are the results the same? Do the same for $H$.
If you're bored, try to see that these two groups are isomorphic.

Comment: @TopologicalKing You will have already received plenty of good indications for an answer, so I want to make a side remark: groups are not defined as ordered triplets but as ordered doublets, whose left component is the support set (i.e. the set carrying the operation) and the right component is the binary operation inducing the group structure. The existence of the neutral element is one of the intrinsic axioms of the group structure and it -- the neutral element itself -- doesn't have to be explicitly added as a third component in the structure, as it suffices that it is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both groups are isomorphic: $G\cong H$, see

[How to prove that two groups $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827123/how-to-prove-that-two-groups-g-and-h-are-isomorphic)

So it suffices to show that, say, $H$ is abelian. But this is clear from
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & 2b \cr b & a \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} c & 2d \cr d & c \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} ac+2bd & 2(ad+bc) \cr ad+bc & ac+2bd \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} c & 2d \cr d & c \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a & 2b \cr b & a \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: One question: the group operation is addition, so instead of using $ xy = yx$ I have to use $x+y = y+x$ to prove if a group is abelian or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to show $a\circ b=b\circ a$, for $\circ=+$ or $\circ=\cdot$, or any other composition $a\circ b$ (for example composition of maps etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some steps for constructing a proof that the group $G$ is abelian:

- Consider any two elements of $G$. These elements can be written in the form $g_1 = a_1 + b_1 \sqrt{2},$ $g_2 = a_2 + b_2 \sqrt{2}$.
- In terms of our variables $a_i$ and $b_i$, write $g_1 + g_2$ in the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$ for suitable $a,b \in \Bbb Q$
- Similarly, write $g_2 + g_1$ in the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$ for suitable $a,b \in \Bbb Q$
- Look at the results from the previous two steps. How can we conclude that $g_1 + g_2$ and $g_2 + g_1$ are equal? (What does it mean for two elements of $G$ to be equal, by the way?)

The proof for $H$ is essentially the same.

Comment: Thankyou for the help!

Comment: You can also take a detour by showing that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, then using (or proving) the statement that if $G$ is abelian and $H \cong G$, then $H$ is abelian.